# Angular, ionic and cordova - App launch time

Tags: angularjs, performance, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing an app using angular, ionic and cordova.

The problem I've got is that my app takes a long time to launch (around 8-10 seconds)

I'd like it to be a bit faster.

I read a lot around, and usually people says "load fewer files and it will be faster..." ok, point taken, the problem I've got is that I am also using a lot of 3rd parties libraries from bower, all compiled into one single bower file, that minified is around 4MB.

I decided to cache bower file using manifest, and apparently (according to google network tab) it now takes (after loading it from the cache) only 600ms instead of 5s, but again, the app appears to me to be still a lot slow to load.

I also tried to move all the files that are not required at the end of `index.html` file, as well as loading them asynchronously using html5 tag `async`.

Still, no luck.

What else can I try?

I am going to include some screenshots so that you can understand a bit better the amount of bower libraries I am using as well as the timeline from chrome

Timeline:

[image: Timeline from chrome]

3rd Party libraries:

[image: 3rd Party libraries]

Also, my index.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="manifest.appcache">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
          content="default-src * gap://ready file: data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; font-src 'self' data: https://fonts.gstatic.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *">


    <title>Heat Genius App</title>
    <link href="css/bower.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.directives.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ionic.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/templates.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="App" class="app" ng-strict-di>
<div class="hg-boxed-container">
    <ion-nav-view class="slide-left-right" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
</div>

<link href="css/vendor.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/bower.js"></script>
<script async  src="js/vendor.js"></script>
<script async  src="cordova.js"></script>
<script async src="js/csv-data.js"></script>
<script async  src="js/hg-doctor-templates.js"></script>
<script async src="https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB0H7djlBcJdz4KnW9ZmFHfqhUJSa8l9AM&libraries=places&"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the manifest file:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2016-12-19 v1.0.0
js/*
css/*
assets/*
```

Any suggestion will be really appreciated, thanks in advance